# Using each line of a file separately in a script

Tags: list, loops, iteration, tweepy

I have a list of 235 twitter IDs in a text file.
like so:

2597319

7445591

273299750

337590061

16510947

21958717

I need to go through each one and get the coordinates for each ID. I have written a script that collects the most common coordinate for an account but currently I have to go through manually changing the ID. I am fairly new to Python so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Below is the start of the script, with the '------' indicating were the ID name should be.

```
#finds unique IDs and saves them in a separate file
lines=open("twitter.txt",'r').readlines()
uniquelines=set(lines)
open("unique.txt",'w').writelines(uniquelines)

auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler('username', 'password')
auth.set_access_token('username', 'password')

api = tweepy.API(auth)
user = api.get_user('------').followers()

#gets 50 tweets from specific ID
statuses = api.user_timeline(id = '------', count = 50)
```